# Rank of matrix with a real parametric number

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Cheers, I am given a matrix $ Α = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 21+λ \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$ and I am being asked to find its rank. I calculate the row echelon form of the matrix, and I end up with $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & -6 & λ \\ 0 & 0 & -\frac{λ}{2}-6 \\ \end{pmatrix}$. Now for the rank, shouldn't I take into account the two possibilities of the last row? So, if $λ \neq -12$, rank(A) = 3, AND if $λ=-12$ rank(A)=2 ? Is my thinking correct? Thanks

Comment: Correct thinking.

Comment: Almost correct. If you field has $2=0$ you cannot form $\lambda/2$. This would arise, for example, in coding theory. So what "number" exactly is your "parametric number"?

Comment: Excuse me, what do you mean by saying "if you field 2 = 0"? Sorry, I just have not came across anything like that, so I don't know why that would be something we should take into account.

Comment: @george.zrs If you are working with real numbers, then you are correct. There are other possible kinds of numbers, but don't worry about that for now.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Do you think a student who asks a question about how to find the rank of an explicit $3 \times 3$ matrix should have heard about the characteristic of a field ? In my opinion, mentioning that "$2$ can be equal to $0$" in this contex is not very pedagogical.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Yes, perhaps you are right. But why could they not explicitly say that we are dealing with real numbers? Very often there is also the question to solve equations, and then they know very well, that $x^2+1=0$ may have solutions - but not real ones. So I find this not unreasonable. Also, very often there are questions about $3\times 3$-matrices with entries in $\Bbb Z/2$. So I suppose they know this, too.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I agree that we see very often questions with a lack of precision, like the ones you are mentionning. However, in my opinion (and it's just my opinion !), here, there is no ambiguity : at the level you learn about rank and matrices, the only numbers you know are $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$. And here, the answer is the same, regardless of the kind of numbers you are considering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. Another point of view would be the following :

First, you see that the two first rows are linearly independant (of course they are not proportional), so this implies that the rank is $\geq 2$, i.e. it is $2$ or $3$.

Moreover, the determinant of the matrix is clearly a one-degree polynomial in $\lambda$, hence there is only one value of $\lambda$ that makes the matrix singular, i.e. that makes the rank equal to $2$.

Finally, to see which is the value, just "notice" that for the last coefficient being equal to $9$, the rows are in arithmetic progression (you have $R_3-R_2=R_2-R_1$), hence the matrix is not invertible : so the only value of $\lambda$ that makes the rank equal to $2$ must satisfy $21+\lambda=9$, so it is $\lambda=-12$.